# What determines the order in which data bound text boxes are filled in a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, bindingsource

I have a form with three text boxes, of which the first and second are bound to the same data binding source. When the form loads, I need the first text box to populate so that the second can use it's data to find it's description and fill the third text box. However, my second text box fills before my first, meaning when the _TextChanged function is called, the first text box's value is an empty string, useless for the third textbox.

What determines the order in which data bound text boxes are filled and how can I change this order so that my first textbox has data when my second text box's _TextChanged function is called?

Comment: You could add a calculated Column / Property to your source of data and bind the second TextBox to it, so when `Current` changes, you already receive the calculated value. Something like the Column of a DataTable with its [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) property set

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. The data table in this regard needs to be able to update an SQL table so if I bind to a non-existent expression column in the table it wouldn't save well. I'm unable to change the binding, I just need to know how to update one before the other.

Comment: Then maybe you can avoid using the TextChanged event of a Control and instead subscribe to the `CurrentChanged` or `PositionChanged` event of your BindingSource and set the Text value of the third TextBox when the event is raised -- In this case, when you setup the data bindings, call first `[BindingSource].SuspendBinding()`, then when all bindings are set, call `[BindingSource].ResumeBinding()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the designer view of the form, you can select View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline.

This window allows you to move the order of controls in the form.